# How to check for string and get the string before after checking

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

If I have a string "3 apples" or "3apples" and do a check like:

```
fruit = "3 apples"

if fruit.find('apples') > -1:
```

How can i get the number 3 before apple if the statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.split` *(assuming the string supplied is in form: `'int(s) apples'` or `'int(s)apples'`)*:

```
fruit = "3 apples"

try:
    num, word = fruit.split()
except ValueError:
    num = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, fruit))
    word = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, fruit))

if word == 'apples':
    print(num)
```

Using `re`:

```
import re

fruit = "3 apples"
match = re.match(r"(\d+)\s*apples$", fruit)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: What if the string was together like "3apples"?

Comment: Then regex is your best option. I will edit.

Comment: use `(\d+)\s*apples$`

Answer (score 0):

you can loop trough the string and find the digits:

```
fruit = "3 apples"

if fruit.find('apples') > -1:
    print("".join([i for i in fruit if i.isdigit() ]))
```

Comment: What if the string is "12 apples"?

Comment: unlikely case, but "2.5 apples"?